# How do you embed in HTML from the creator's IP address?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.randomExample.com" width=100% height=768px>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make an embed for randomExample.com. I make the above code and it works fine. However, because iFrame shows the website if it were to be looked up by the user, on a separate computer, randomExample.com is blocked.
So, instead of displaying the iFrame from the client's perspective, I want to display it from the creator's perspective.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to build a proxy, where your server looks up the (potentially blocked) site for your user and sends the resulting markup from _your_ domain to the end user.

It can become pretty complicated, especially when randomExample.com requests additional resources, like its images, CSS, and JavaScript, or other items after pageload.

What technology are you using? That will help you get an answer more specific to your situation.

Comment: Late 2013 iMac. MacOS 10.4.3. 5 ghz wifi.